# How to set the parent class of an unordered list

Tags: jquery

I have the following ul setup:

```
        <div id="sidebar">
        <ul id="themenu" class="sf-menu sf-vertical">

            <li>
                <a class="sf-with-ul topm" href="#">Musical Instruments</a>
                <ul class="bullet">
                    <li><a href="#">Guitars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Drums</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Keyboards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Brass</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

My question is, in addition to the above, I have other top-level menus with sub-menus that when a top-level menu is selected, it is highlighted "Green" based on a class I have created called "currentMenu".

My jQuery works fine for top-level menu items for setting them to "Green" as each top-level menu is toggled but what I am unsure how to do, is that when the user selects say the sub-menu "Drums" in the above code, I want it's parent top-level menu set to "currentMenu" class.
In this case, the top-level button "Musical Instruments" would be set.

I am unsure how to do. I tried something like:

```
    $('ul.sf-menu li a').click(function() {

        if($(this).hasClass('nosub')) {
            $("ul.sf-menu li ul li a").removeClass("currentSubMenu");
        }
        else {
            $("ul.sf-menu li a").not(this).removeClass("currentMenu");
            $("ul.bullet li a").parent().this.addClass("currentMenu");
        }
    });
```

It's this line I'm not sure about:

```
$("ul.bullet li a").parent().this.addClass("currentMenu");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* this is what you're after.  Instead of this:

```
$("ul.bullet li a").parent().this.addClass("currentMenu");
```

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get there, like this:

```
$(this).closest('.sf-menu > li').children('a').addClass('currentMenu');
```

This goes from the link you clicked on up to the first level `<li>` it's in, and applies the `.currentMenu` class to it's `<a>` child.

---

Or, if you want `.currentClass` applied at each level you're in, you can do this:

```
$(this).parents('li').children('a').addClass('currentMenu')
       .end().siblings().children('a').removeClass("currentMenu");
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/yq8pm/1/).

Comment: Thanks Nick - haven't tried it yet but basically added the following info to my post: "In this case, the top-level button "Musical Instruments" would be set."

Comment: @tonsils - In that case the `.closest()` option seems like what you're after :)

Comment: it surely does. That did it. Really appreciate your help.